# Decipher a deadlock situation in an OSGi code piece

Tags: java, multithreading, osgi, deadlock

The following piece of code is to demonstrate a deadlock that may happen in a piece of OSGi code, and taken directly from the freely downloadable book: [osgi in practice (Neil Bartlett)](http://njbartlett.name/osgibook.html). The book is generally easy to follow and I've found it to be very useful. However, I'm not sure I follow the concurrency problem identified (and slightly discussed) in page 130. The code is as follows:

```
package org.osgi.book.reader.dbmailbox;

public class BadLockingMailboxRegistrationService implements MailboxRegistrationService {

    private final Map<String,ServiceRegistration> map = 
            new HashMap<String,ServiceRegistration >();

    private final BundleContext context ;

    public BadLockingMailboxRegistrationService(BundleContext context) { 
        this . context = context ;
    }

    // DO NOT DO THIS!
    public synchronized void registerMailbox ( String name, Mailbox mailbox){

        ServiceRegistration priorReg = map.get(name);

        if(priorReg != null) priorReg . unregister ();

        Properties props = new Properties (); 
        props.put(Mailbox.NAME_PROPERTY , name); 
        ServiceRegistration reg = 
                context . registerService (Mailbox.class.getName(), mailbox , props ); 
        map . put(name , reg );
    } 
}
```

The discussion provided to show how deadlock may happen is:

> To translate this unhappy situation to OSGi programming, imagine that
>   a thread has taken a lock on an object F. Then it tries to call our
>   register- Mailbox, which locks object K — but it must wait, perhaps
>   because another thread is already executing registerMailbox. One of
>   the callbacks resulting from the service registration then attempts to
>   lock F . The result: two starving threads and no work done.

I understand the first part of the discussion, i.e. that a thread may take a lock on an Object F, which attempts to call *registerMailbox*, thus taking a lock on object K (where K is the service object registered for this particular service, or so I think!). Now sure, another thread is already executing *registerMailbox*. That means, it also needs to hold lock on K (since OSGi distributes a singleton service object). Now where is the callback(s) discussed which may attempt to take a lock on F, thus causing deadlock?

Comment: The book doesn't demonstrate this problem in terms of actually using a service consumer for the aforementioned service. Hence, I may not be interpreting the provided discussion correctly as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is noting that `context.registerService` notifies listeners of service registrations on the same thread during its execution. If one of those listeners in turn attempts to acquire lock `F` it will result in a deadlock since `F` is held by the thread that also holds `K`.

Thread 2: invoke `registerMailbox` and acquire `K`

Thread 1: acquire `F` before invoking `registerMailbox`, then invoke `registerMailbox` which is synchronized, thus attempts to acquire `K` but blocks because it is held by Thread 2

Thread 2: finally executes `context.registerService` which in turn invokes a listener/callback that attempts to acquire `F`, and blocks since it is held by Thread 1

Because there are two locks acquired by two threads in opposite order and each acquires one of them but not the second, deadlock occurs. This is not really an OSGI-specific issue, but I suppose is illustrated to note that service registration involves listener notification and should be invoked when locks are held with caution.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to say, yes. More generally, don't hold locks when calling into unknown code... and when you invoke a service, or register/unregister a service in OSGi, you're *always* calling unknown code.

Comment: Thanks.. the key concept I was missing was that invoking a service, and/or register/unregistering services in OSGi is calling unknown code, thus could lead to deadlocks. BTW, any plans on getting the book onto production so I could keep it on a shelf?